# Which std container behaviour is this?

Tags: c++, stl, containers, std, stdvector

I am trying to "hack" a game (Red Alert 3, closed source..) which is compiled using Visual Studio 2005 (MSVCR80.dll's needed to play),

I try to make a program which shows the unit list of my opponents. As for that I first need to find a (static) pointer to my own list which I can do on singleplayer.

I have a few problems because I cannot figure out if my static pointers really point to what I want.

I have noticed this behaviour: (by looking at which addresses are changed by the add_unit code):

- if a units hasn't been build yet, create a new address for it (random?) and set the value to 1 (amount of units of that type), but all other addresses remain unchanged for previously added units, so if a unit of type A has the address 0x12345678 which tells how many units of type A there are, then it doesn't change and remains accessible throughout the game session.

So the other addresses aren't invalidated or something?

This is an example of the addresses which are added, the highlighted one is the first on which was added: 
[image]

What types of std::containers could be used for this?
It's certainly not a vector because a vector would invalidate all the other addresses when inserting a new element, or not?

---

Edit/Update:
as for now I have been able to reconstruct this structure:

```
struct UnitsInfo
{
    DWORD * someptr_1_to_other_UnitsInfo_struct;
    DWORD * someptr_2_to_other_UnitsInfo_struct;
    DWORD * someptr_3_to_other_UnitsInfo_struct;
    int unkown_1;
    unsigned int Type;
    unsigned int Amount;
};
```

and the some_ptr stuff points around all other unit addresses, I need to find out how it works. Then I can efficiently create everything.

Comment: Adding to a vector doesn't necessarily mean invalidation of addresses. Also, to avoid re-allocation, I'd guess the size is fixed beforehand (IIRC you're limited to the number of units you can have, so an array of size 200 could be enough)

Comment: those addresses don't seem to be uniformely distributed, so by doing  vector_start+(offset*element) wouldn't work :( that's why I think this is not a std::vector too

Comment: Maybe a linked list? These have "arbitrary" addresses. (I think they are allocated contiguously in the beginning, but when elements are inserted / deleted, they won't still be contiguous...)

Comment: You don't create addresses. You create objects that are stored in memory at some addresses. Those addresses represent the start location of the object that contain information about the unit, I guess. I don't think they have anything to do with the type of container used to store those objects.

Comment: hm after a few more studies I think it's an advanced linked list, now I need to figure out the structure hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be in ascending address. This looks like things are being added to whatever container via an allocator. I'd guess and intrusively linked list where the objects are on an allocator of some sort.

I hope this helps.